# Using Observables and subscribing to its changes- which solution is better?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

[I have asked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188433/angular-using-observables-and-subscribing-to-its-changes) this question on Code Review StackExchange but there are far fewer people there and none has answered my question so I decided to ask here. Please don't eat me for that. If there is a better community to ask please point me there and I will delete this question from here.

I have a component and a service. The service is contacting an API and gets a data which should be handled in the component. Now, I can do it in two ways:

1. Create a public `Observable` in my service and the component is subscribed to it and handle changes
2. All methods in my service return `Observable`s and the component subscribes to every call and then handles the changes.

Let me show a minimal example.

So this is the **first** solution:

**my-service.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    requestObservable: Observable<any>;
    private requestObserver: Observer<any>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {

        this.requestObservable = new Observable<any>(observer => {
            this.requestObserver = observer;
        });

    }

    get(id: string): void {
        this.http
        .get(`/some/url/${id}`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(
            next => this.requestObserver.next(next)
        );
    }

}
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {

        this.myService.requestObservable.subscribe(
            next => this.handleChanges(next)
        );

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.myService.get(1);
        this.myService.get(2);

    }

    handleChanges(changes: any): void {

        console.log(changes);

    }

}
```

And this is the same situation but solved in the **second** way:

**my-service.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    get(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
        .get(`/some/url/${id}`)
        .map(response => response.json());
    }

}
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.myService.get(1).subscribe(
            next => {
                console.log(next);
            }
        );

        this.myService.get(2).subscribe(
            next => {
                console.log(next);
            }
        );

    }

}
```

---

So as you can see both examples are doing the same thing but in other ways. I have omitted unnecessary `import`s and other things because they are not connected with my problem.

I would say that the first solution is much cleaner since it gives me a possibility to have multiple calls to the same `get()` method and have one method which handles all of them.

On the other hand, if I had more different methods in my service and every one of them would have to use different `Observable` then it would make my service more complicated and low-readable.

Please advice which solution is better?

Comment: Possibly neither of the above. It's unclear why you do multiple requests in one place and what exactly should happen on request completion instead of bogus `console.log(changes)`.

Comment: It's just an example. Say, I have a table and want to load new data on page change. Then on each click on the next page, the new `get` request will happen. But also there is a "Rows per page" select and changing this one also will trigger another `get`. Now, how should I handle this? I don't want to load all data at once because it's too many rows and in most cases, not all of them will be necessary

Comment: Well, Solution 1 looks more like antipattern to me, but this may depend on the case (it won't be antipattern if you need side effects on requestObservable like throttling). Btw, requestObserver is yucky, there are subjects for that. Instead of solution 2, you could do `Observable.merge(myService.get(1), myService.get(2)).subscribe(...)`. The case with pagination could also be handled with a router (also good if you need to keep pagination state in url).

Comment: In my opinion "a service must return observables". So you can, in the component, use forkJoin, or switchMap or merge. Ah! use httpClient, not the "old" http